# Code smells reporting/tracking tool

Tags: coding-style

I was wondering if you know any tools that help keep track of "[code smells](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CodeSmell)". So that team members could report some finding in the code and then possibly vote on the most problematic ones (in terms of future project development).

Any experiences?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [find bugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) or [check style](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)?  Both of these are pretty good for this.

I would also recommend [pmd](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/).  These let you analyse common problems such as not setting method parameters final.

Lastly, I'd recommend using [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) as this will highlight any code errors in order of priority.  Such as code that is knowingly going to through a NPE, it will highlight this to you and can be integrated with Jenkins.

All these together can really help you move towards the "Clean Code" mantra.

Comment: These tools seem to focus on automatic detection of code smells. Whereas I am interested in more manual approach where team members are actually reporting only what drives them mad.

Comment: In that case, you could write your own rules in check style or PMD.  I've done something similar as I always got sick of people using duplicate GUIDs so I've started writing my own rule for duplicate GUID strings.  You could then integrate these rules into Sonar so they fire automatically.

Comment: Still, this approach would assume that I can formalize code smell in terms of rules. I don't want it. I would prefer to consider each case separately and let developer decide whether a part of code needs to be refactored. 

Then Jira or Bugzilla would be fine. However these are "general purpose" tools. I hoped there are some tools dedicated to keep track of parts of code (with some enhancements like code context information, class collaborators, usage etc.).